# Node posting via querystring fails, yet in jQuery AJAX it's fine

Tags: ajax, node.js, eventbrite

Seeking some help on the following:

Why does the following work and return a 200 (setting an event)

```
$.ajax({url : 'https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/?token=<MYTOKEN>&event.name.html=bob%20smith&event.start.utc=2015-12-13T10:39:35Z&event.start.timezone=Europe/London&event.end.utc=2015-12-13T10:39:35Z&event.currency=GBP&event.end.timezone=Europe/London', type: 'POST', data : {}})
```

When the following node POST does not?

```
// post data
var post_options = {
    host: 'https://www.eventbriteapi.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/v3/events/?token=<TOKEN>&event.name.html='+ encodeURIComponent(name) +'&event.start.utc=2015-12-13T10:39:35Z&event.start.timezone=Europe/London&event.end.utc=2015-12-13T10:39:35Z&event.currency='+ encodeURIComponent(currency) +'&event.end.timezone=Europe/London',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
};

var httpreq = http.request(post_options, function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    //response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf8'});
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log('%s', chunk);
    });
    response.on('end', function () {
        res.send('ok')
    });
});
```

The response is a 403 yet logging what was actually sent in the Node POST is identical to the AJAX call:

```
method: 'POST',
path: '/v3/events/?token=<MYTOKEN>&event.name.html=bob%20smith&event.start.utc=2015-12-13T10:39:35Z&event.start.timezone=Europe/London&event.end.utc=2015-12-13T10:39:35Z&event.currency=gbp&event.end.timezone=Europe/London'
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're using a `POST` method with no request body and all the parameters in the querystring? Why not just use a `GET` at that point?

Comment: It's based on the API for EventBrite, it **must** be a post (to create the event) and they won't accept serialized data e.g. **event["time"]["start"**], it must be in dot syntax event.time.start which is bonkers, I am aware!

Comment: I was more curious why you weren't posting the data as the request body instead of as querystring parameters. Generally when `POST`ing to a url you would pass data in the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out the node module request (`npm install request`). It makes HTTP requests significantly easier to deal with:

```
var request = require('request');
request.post({
    url: "http://my_url.com",
    form: {
        key: "value" // post data goes here
    }
}, function(error, response, body) {
    // body contains your data
});
```

Comment: This worked as I'm able to send in the dot notation required by the API, it's just ashame they won't accept stringified json and could've have sent without the need for the extra package!